# Google custom search api - Limit results to 1 per domain

Tags: google-custom-search

Is there any way to limit the results returned by the Google Custom Search API to 1 per domain?

Answer (score -4):

Yes. If you're looking for the first result. Then you can try the following if you are familiar with Python.

```
res = service.cse().list(query,cx='YOURSEARCHENGINEIDHERE,).execute()

name = res['items'][0]['title']     #title of the first search result
url = res['items'][0]['link']       #url of the first search result
```

Comment: what you are doing is taking the first result of each domain from the response i.e. if there are 10 results you will take 7 unique domain results from it(if 3 are repeating).
what I am looking for is 10 unique results from google api itself.
Correct me if my understanding of your response is incorrect.

Comment: @GunmeetSingh Did you find a way to do so ?